# Unserialize JSON string

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this code

```
        string jsonString = "{\r\n  \"value1\":\"value2\" \r\n}";

        string normalString = "value4";

        NameValueCollection collection = new NameValueCollection();
        collection["First"] = jsonString;
        collection["Second"] = normalString;

        var nvcDictionary = collection.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => collection[k]);

        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nvcDictionary);
```

which produces

```
        {\"First\":\"{\\r\\n  \\\"value1\\\":\\\"value2\\\" \\r\\n}\",\"Second\":\"value4\"}
```

but I want it like this

```
        {\"First\":\"{\"value1\":\"value2\"}\",\"Second\":\"value4\"}
```

I have tried

```
        Regex.Unescape(jsonString);
```

and

```
        jsonString = jsonString.Replace("\r\n", "");
        jsonString = jsonString.Replace("\\", "");
```

but I cant seem to "unserialize" the jsonString in the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not exactly what I wanted but I will solve it like this

```
        string jsonString = "{\r\n  \"value1\":\"value2\" \r\n}";

        string normalString = "value4";

        var parsedJson = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
        string valuefromJsonString = parsedJson["value1"].ToString();

        NameValueCollection collection = new NameValueCollection();
        collection["First"] = valuefromJsonString;
        collection["Second"] = normalString;

        var nvcDictionary = collection.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => collection[k]);

        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nvcDictionary);
```

which produces

```
      {\"First\":\"value2\",\"Second\":\"value4\"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you remove the Newlines before you process?

```
string jsonString = "{\r\n  \"value1\":\"value2\" \r\n}";
jsonString = jsonString.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
```

When I run that, the result has a value of

```
"{\"First\":\"{  \\\"value1\\\":\\\"value2\\\" }\",\"Second\":\"value4\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to convert the json string to a dictionary, you can deserialize your string to a dictionary using `JsonConvert.Deserialize<T>()` method and then create a new dictionary based on that.

```
string jsonString = "{\r\n  \"value1\":\"value2\" \r\n}";
string normalString = "value4";
            
Dictionary<string, string> dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonString);
Dictionary<string, string> newDict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "First", dict["value1"] },
    { "Second", normalString }
};
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newDict));

// Prints:
{"First":"value2","Second":"value4"}
```